# System.FormatException in mscorlib.dll for DateTime conversion

Tags: c#, datetime, formatexception

I'm trying to convert an Active Directory attribute (whenCreated) into DateTime then String, but I keep getting a FormatException, any ideas why? Here is the code:

```
string format = "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.0Z";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(sResult.Properties["whenCreated"][0].ToString(),format,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string whenCreated = dt.ToString();
```

Also, `sResult.Properties["whenCreated"][0].ToString()` is the result from an Active Directory search (the date retrieved) and has the String (Generalized Time) syntax.

Comment: have you debugged the code? what value does sResult.Properties["whenCreated"][0] contains?

Comment: What is the actual value of the string?

Comment: The string is an Active Directory attribute with String (Generalized Time) Syntax as described by MS https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684436%28v=vs.85%29.aspx . I've made a format mistake I will fix in post(but still doesn't work).

Comment: "FormatException" means the format is wrong. Fix the format, and post *actual* strings. You already have all the information needed to debug this error, while this question has none (apart from the wrong format)

Comment: Does the value in the debugger seem to match that?

Comment: You're specifying `MM` twice in your format string - does that sound right to you? Have you read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx ?

Comment: What is the type of `sResult.Properties["whenCreated"][0]` to start with? It may already be a `DateTime`, in which case you should just cast instead of formatting and then parsing...

Comment: This is the exact way I found to parse `sResult.Properties["whenCreated"][0]` directly using `DateTimeOffset`: `DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(sResult.Properties["whenCreated"][0].ToString(), "yyyyMMddhhmmss'.0'zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`. I may post this if it's right.

Comment: Jon skeet: this is the format, I said above: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684436%28v=vs.85%29.aspx 
And no it's not a DateTime, SearchResultCollection.Properties["whenCreated"][0] returns a Property object, hence the toString.

Comment: In order to format the date strings linked in that msdn documentation, see my answer

Comment: @Flexabustbergson - You need to use the `@` notification system when replying to someone. Typing "Jon skeet" doesn't raise a notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DateTime.ParseExact method expects a format string, that tells it where in the input string is which component of a valid date. Your format of 'd' does not meet this criteria. I don't know the content of your input (would help if you add it). But lets assume it would be "2017/31/05 10:27:45" for today. Your format string would then have to be: "yyyy/dd/MM HH:mm:ss"

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("2017/31/05 10:27:45","yyyy/dd/MM HH:mm:ss",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Yes I just saw that, and fixed in my post. The format I put now is the one I retrieve from my input string.

Comment: And what is an example value, you get from the Active Directory?

Comment: 02/09/2008 11:26:38. Ok sorry really bad question. This solves my problem, I'm used to Active Directory attribute accountExpires which has a particular format and thought all dates in AD would have to be converted but this fits my needs. Thanks for help!

Comment: @Flexabustbergson: Even with a different value, the format string you specified in the question would be wrong. You really need to read the docs for custom format strings.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684436%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) linked by the OP:

> The format for the Generalized-Time syntax is "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.0Z". An example of an acceptable value is "20010928060000.0Z"

And:

> If the time is specified in a time zone other than GMT, the differential between the time zone and GMT is appended to the string instead of "Z" in the form "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.0[+/-]HHMM". An example of an acceptable value is "20010928060000.0+0200"

So you'd need two format strings in order to parse the strings, like this:

```
string adDate = "20010928060000.0Z";
string adDate2 = "20010928060000.0+0200";

string format = "yyyyMMddhhmmss.0Z";
string format2 = "yyyyMMddhhmmss.0zzz";
DateTime dtdtdt = DateTime.ParseExact(adDate2, new string[] { format, format2 }, 
                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Comment: The "Z" represents UTC offset (with +/- sign), it may still produces "String not recognized as valid DateTime".